# Numeric 2D Integral with singularity along line, slow convergence

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to calculate the integral

```
f[x0_, y0_] := NIntegrate[x/(Sqrt[x^2 - x0^2]y^2 (y^5 + y0)) (1./(1. + y) + Log[1 + y] - 1.),{x, x0, Infinity}, {y, x, Infinity}, Exclusions -> {x == x0},
    Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", 
 "SingularityHandler" -> "Automatic", "SingularityDepth" -> 4, 
 "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 5000}, MaxRecursion -> 250, AccuracyGoal -> 4];
```

over a large range of values x0,y0 (10^(-6) to 1000 for each).
 For a lot of points I get the warning

```
NIntegrate::slwcon :  Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
```

Often changing the integration strategy or options may remove some of the problem points I've tested, but this seems to then instead give other problem points.

As for the warning, I've tried increasing the working precision without result and the integrand doesn't seem to be oscillating and the singularity should be covered by the exclusion. In fact I would prefer to have a higher precisiongoal than above if possible but the main problem is that even using accuracygoal instead on a low setting still gives warnings.

As for speed a slowdown of the integral by a factor of 100 wouldn't be a problem if i can get better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a change of variables `x -> u^2 + x0` to remove the singularity.

```
x/(Sqrt[x - x0] Sqrt[x + x0] y^2 (y^5 + y0)) (1/(1 + y) + Log[1 + y] - 1) * 
     2 u /.                    (* Jacobian factor *)
      x -> u^2 + x0 /.         (* substitution *)
       {1/Sqrt[u^2] -> 1/u}    (* simplification *)
(*  (2 (u^2 + x0) (-1 + 1/(1 + y) + Log[1 + y]))/(Sqrt[u^2 + 2 x0] y^2 (y^5 + y0))  *)

f2[x0_, y0_] := 
  NIntegrate[
    (2 (u^2 + x0) (-1 + 1/(1 + y) + Log[1 + y]))/(Sqrt[u^2 + 2 x0] y^2 (y^5 + y0)), 
    {u, 0, Infinity}, {y, u^2 + x0, Infinity}];
```

Here's a check on powers of ten:

```
Outer[Quiet@Check[f2[10^#1, 10^#2]; {}, {##}] &, Range[-6, 3, 1], Range[-6, 3, 1]]
```

The output is an array of all `{}`, indicating there were no error/warning messages.

Comment: Excellent answer, this works perfectly! Thanks!